# How can reactive programming react to database changes?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I am new in the topic reactive programming and therefore have some questions.

I am developing a small software.
I would like to take the opportunity to get to know reactive programming better.

So I looked at Spring's project-reactor.
I also use R2DBC to reactively access the database.

I would like to know if there is any way that database responds to changes.

Or rather: If a user saves an entry in the database, then servers (for example, RestController) should be notified.

How could I go about doing that?

Enresponding controllers, configuration, entities, etc. I have already implemented.

Sorry for spelling mistakes.

Complement: The updates to the frontend are then made by Server Sent Events.

Comment: Thanks for your great question. One thing: Project Reactor is not a Spring project and it does not depend on Spring.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what Nick Tsitlakidis mentioned. Let me add a couple of things here.

The typical database query pattern is to query for a number of records. Databases respond with their results and indicate that the query is complete once a server has sent all records to your application. If new records arrive while the query is active or after the query is complete, you do not see these changes immediately because the of isolation and in case the query is complete, then you no longer have a reference to the query.

The feature you're asking is event-driven consumption of data. Databases call this feature continuous queries. Some stores (such as [MongoDB with Tailable cursors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) or [Postgres Logical Decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-explanation.html)) come with features that allow keeping a cursor/query open and your client is able to receive continuous updates.

Kafka and JMS also follow the idea of sending (messages) that are consumed typically by listeners or even through a reactive stream.

So it all boils down to the technology that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that reactor can't solve this problem for you on its own. If you want your application to respond (react) on some database change, then you need to identify who's making this change and implement some kind of integration there.

Example, if you have `Service1` updating the database, and `Service2` needs to respond then `Service1` can either call `Service2`, or, you can emit an event from `Service1` and listen for the event from `Service2`.

The first approach is simpler and easier to implement but it has the disantvantage that is couples the two services. The second is trickier to implement but services are decoupled.

Reactor can help you in both cases : 
For events, reactor can give you a way to listen to the events. For example using the [reactor-rabbitmq](https://projectreactor.io/docs/rabbitmq/release/reference/) module or the [reactor-kafka](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/).
For service-to-service calls, reactor can help you if you use [Spring Webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html).

Perhaps you can tell us more about your case so we can provide a more specific solution?

Comment: Using a database with push architecture like RethinkDB is also an optional to stream data realtime